# alert session end with server sent events

Tags: asp.net, html, session, signalr, server-sent-events

I want to send a message to the client when the ASP.NET session ends. I did not want to use timers so I tried using "server sent events" to call the client from the session_end event in global.asax. Is there a way to call a specific client from global.asax? I tried using the 'SignalR' library for this propose, but had problems calling a specific client from Global.asax (I have managed to call a group of clients but not a specific client)
What are the best practices for this propose?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but does [this help](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout.aspx)?

(Of course you don't need to use DevExpress for this, you can implement your own popup window)

Comment: This solution offers a use of javascript timers. I do not want to use javascript timers